# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'attributes' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, fields-attributes, geocoding, mmqgis, unboundlocalerror

When trying to 'Geocode' a CSV file I receive this answer:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'attributes' referenced before assignment
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/user/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/mmqgis/mmqgis_dialogs.py", line 1384, in run output_file_name, not_found_file_name, self.mmqgis_status_callback)
>
> File "/home/user/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/mmqgis/mmqgis_library.py", line 2087, in mmqgis_geocode_web_service notwriter.writerow(attributes) UnboundLocalError: local variable 'attributes' referenced before assignment
>
> Versión Python: 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34) [GCC 8.0.1
> 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]]
>
> Versión QGIS: 3.8.1-Zanzibar Zanzibar, dcd95cc648

I've already read a lot of posts and [this](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python/), but I don't understand it.

Comment: It's a bug. Report it to the plugin author here - https://github.com/michaelminn/mmqgis/issues  You may wish to edit your question and ask how to geocode a CSV another way because the MMQGIS plugin is not working.

Comment: Sorry, I see I never answered. I reported it some time ago, but the problem still exists...

Comment: Looks like that project is dead, no commits for 3 years. Suggest you research / ask a new question about how to geocode in qgis